# Stop AuCTeX from asking for a master file everytime I compile for the first time after reopening Emacs

Tags: auctex, file-local-variables, local-variables

Since I work with multifile-documents, I put `(setq-default TeX-master 'nil)` in my init.el.

Everytime I compile for the first time in a new Emacs-session, I get queried for the master file. The first time for a new file, this is expected behaviour, but then Auctex should know it, because of the local variable and not query again.[1]

The variable gets set everytime, since in the end of my file I have for example:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "../main"
%%% TeX-master: "../main"
%%% TeX-master: "../main"
%%% End:
```

But for some reason, despite this, I get queried every time. Maybe this has something to do with the file-parsing.

[1]: source, Auctex manual p.70 "To avoid asking you again, AUCTEX will automatically insert the name of the master file as a file variable (see Section “File Variables” in The Emacs Editor)."

Comment: But in order for the file variable to be known to Emacs, the file has to be saved and closed and then reopened. Alternatively, you can say `M-x normal-mode`: that will read the file variable(s).  See if that works.

Comment: Hm, running `M-x normal-mode` yields: 
File mode specification error: (error Autoloading file /home/X/.emacs.d/straight/build/auctex/tex.elc failed to define function flycheck-mode)
That could be the reason why it does not read the variable.

Comment: I resolved the errors (there were indeed multiple) and it works as intented. Thank you!